# untar tar file using --strip-components=1

Tags: linux, tar

I have a tar file which has multiple folders like this:

```
code.tar
  bin/
    startup.sh
  WebServer/
    appname
    webappname
  Configuration/
    a.properties
    b.properties
```

If I unzip code.tar, I get a folder name `code` with all the folder structure under it, but I want to extract the contents of `code.tar` and just get the sub-folder structure under it (ie `bin/`, `WebServer/`, `configuration/` and files in these folders).

When I use `tar -xzf code.tar -C <path> --strip-components=1` I get all the contents of subfolders ie `startup.sh`,`appname` etc along with the sub-folders-

eg on running above command I get all these folders and files at same level-

```
bin/
startup.sh
WebServer/
appname
webappname
Configuration/
a.properties
b.properties
```

please help

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what is your question?

Answer (score 7):

Your command seems right.

Suppose you have folder "extract" you want to extract the file to:

```
tar -xzf code.tar -C extract --strip-components=1
```

So this will truncate the upper folder "code" and just extract the contents with the file-folder structure preserved.

Answer (score 1):

There's no explicit flag to allow tar to only extract the files at that depth and not the files any deeper (which is what I'm interpreting the question to mean); Generally you would need to explicitly specify what's to be extracted; e.g.

```
tarfile="foo.tar.xz"
tar -xf "$tarfile" --strip-components=1 $(tar tf $tarfile | awk -F/ '{if (NF <= 2 && $NF != "") print; }')
```

We use the list of entries from tar (`tar tf`) and filter through awk, where when we find any entries with `<= 2` items, and that isn't a directory (`$NF != ""`) then we print them.

This will give you all the files that need to be extracted from the archive, which is then passed to an explicit extraction command.

Comment: I think I was not clear. The command that you gave provided me with all the files ( not directories). While I want the top level directories to be extracted.

Comment: So I just want to drop "code" folder but want to keep the entire folder structure under it as is-

bin/
    startup.sh
  WebServer/
    appname
    webappname
  Configuration/
    a.properties
    b.properties